# Rock Paper Scissors Game - Efficiency?

Tags: java

I made a Rock Paper Scissors game for my CS class (senior in highschool) and the shell file my teacher gave me noted that I have to put the do while loop in the runner, but I don't see why? My code works, but she said it'd be better to write it in the runner? Why? Also, how can I write it more efficiently? (Note: I'm a total beginner, and prior to taking this class, had no knowledge of coding. Haven't learned recursion yet.)

my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RockPapersScissors {
  private String user;
  private int computer;

  public RockPapersScissors(){
    setPlayers(" ");
  }

  public RockPapersScissors(String s){
    setPlayers(s);
  }

  public void setPlayers(String s){
    user=s;
  }

  public void play(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random num = new Random();
    int numUser = 0;
    String playAgain = "";
    do{
      System.out.print("Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon[R,P,S] :: ");
      user = keyboard.next();
      System.out.println("player has "+ user);

      switch(user){
        case "R": numUser = 0; break;
        case "P": numUser = 1; break;
        case "S": numUser = 2; break;
        case "r": numUser = 0; break;
        case "p": numUser = 1; break;
        case "s": numUser = 2; break;
        default: System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice. Restart game.\n"); continue;
      }

      computer = num.nextInt(3);

      switch(computer){
        case 0: System.out.println("computer has R"); break;
        case 1: System.out.println("computer has P"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("computer has S"); break;
      }

      if(numUser == computer){
        System.out.println("!Draw Game!");
      }else if(numUser == 0){
        if(computer == 1){
          System.out.println("!Computer Wins <<Paper Covers Rock>>!");
        }if(computer == 2){
          System.out.println("!Player Wins <<Rock Breaks Scissors>>!");
        }
      }else if(numUser == 1){
        if(computer == 2){
          System.out.println("!Computer Wins <<Scissors cuts paper>>!");
        }if(computer == 0){
          System.out.println("!Player Wins <<Paper Covers Rock>>!");
        }
      }else if(numUser == 2){
        if(computer == 0){
          System.out.println("!Computer Wins <<Rock Breaks Scissors>>!");
        }if(computer == 1){
          System.out.println("!Player Wins <<Scissors cuts paper>>!");
        }
      }

      System.out.print("\nDo you want to play again? ");
      playAgain = keyboard.next();
      System.out.println("\n");

    }while(playAgain.equals("y") || playAgain.equals("yes") || playAgain.equals("Y"));

    System.out.println("Goodbye.");
    keyboard.close();

  }
}
```

my runner:

```
public class RPSRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RockPapersScissors test = new RockPapersScissors();
    test.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: If this code really works, then this question might be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think this more boils down the fact you have your input (your Scanner) tied to the game model (your play method). If you wanted to modify this code to use an input file rather than standard input, you would need to revamp your play method. Not positive if that's what they are looking for but that's my first thought.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the notion of what a "game" is. If a game is assumed to be a single round of RPS, with no keeping of score, then the teacher's prescribed solution would be good.

However, as soon as you need to retain some form of session state between rounds, such as a score, then you would have to make a design decision: Does the runner contain the logic to keep score, or does the game? Typically, one would have the game keep score, and the runner should know as little as possible about the internal logic of the game.

In another case, you may be asked to expand the runner so that you can choose between two different games. The second game might be "Black Jack", in which case you not only need to keep score, but also keep track of which cards have been played. As you can see the, the complexity of the runner can grow needlessly with your teacher's approach.

The teacher should have given you better requirements, or you should have asked. 
By the way, this happens all the time in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that each round of Rock/Paper/Scissors is independent of all the others.  I would have written a single method that took in player 1 and 2 values and returned a winner.  Get that to work and then put it in the game loop to play over and over again.

There could be a second overloaded version of play() method with an embedded computer player that would randomly choose and call the two-player version.

Perhaps that is what your teacher meant, too.  Why not ask them instead of making us read his/her mind?  You can learn a lot using the Socratic method.

Don't worry about efficiency; it doesn't matter for such a trivial application.  Make it run; make it run correctly; make it run fast.